# Using Amazon SimpleDB with Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to use Amazon's SimpleDB with an application I am building.

I am having trouble finding a *full* tutorial on Amazon's site. So I was wondering if anyone could provide a tutorial on this? Hopefully someone can share their knowledge.

Comment: As someone who recently removed SimpleDB from a production codebase: I recommend staying away. Far, far away.